# Pyspark: How to count the number of each equal distance interval in RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `RDD[Double]`, I want to divide the `RDD` into `k` equal intervals, then count the number of each equal distance interval in RDD.

For example, the `RDD` is like `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,10]`. I want to divided it into `10` equal intervals, so the intervals are `[0,1), [1,2), [2,3), [3,4), [4,5), [5,6), [6,7), [7,8), [8,9), [9,10]`.

As you can see, each element of RDD will be in one of the intervals. Then I want to calculate the number of each interval. Here, there are one element in `[0,1),[1,2),[2,3),[3,4),[4,5),[5,6)`, and both `[6,7)` and `[7,8)` have two element. `[9,10]` has one element.

Finally I expected an array like `array([1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,0,1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I have assumed that first element of the range is inclusive and last exclusive. Please confirm on this. For example when considering the range [0,1] and element is 0 the condition is element >= 0 and element < 1.

```
for index_upper, element_upper in enumerate(array_range):
  counter = 0
  for index, element in enumerate(rdd.collect()):
    if element >= element_upper[0] and element < element_upper[1] :
      counter +=1
  countElementsWithinRange.append(counter)

print(rdd.collect())
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 10]
print(countElementsWithinRange)
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by applying `map` function to `RDD` in order to get the No. of intervals, and then I use `reduceByKey` to get the number of each inbtervals.

Comment: Hi, guy. I find `rdd.collect()` will spend much time, and I want to know are there any method which doesn't need to `collect` rdd.